# Php array with ajax pass/send to other php file and in the other php file use as array with foreach

Tags: php, ajax

Have input form like `<input type="text" name="record_date[] ...`

Part of ajax that sends form to other php file is

```
var values = $("form").serialize();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
data: { 'Values' : values },
dataType: 'json',
```

The other php file receives data

```
$values = $_POST['Values'];
```

As understand this `parse_str($_POST['Values'],$output);` creates array (`$output` is array)

But with this `print_r(json_encode($output));` I see nothing (expected to see array with values etc.)

If use `echo json_encode($output['record_date']);` then all works and get entered values.

Trying to create array and then to use the array like this

```
 foreach ($output as $i=>$output_value ) {
 echo json_encode($output_value[$i]);
 }
```

Changed to this `echo json_encode($output_value['record_date'][$i]);` but in both case echo nothing.

As I understand main question is how to "modify/convert" `parse_str($_POST['Values'],$output);` to php array

`$_POST['Values']` looks like this: `record_date%5B%5D=02.07.2013&record_date%5B%5D=01.07.2013`

Possibly instead of `parse_str` need to use something else

**Update**

If in ajax use `dataType: 'json',` and in php

```
foreach ($output as $key => $output_value) {
echo json_encode($output_value);
}
```

then get nothing.

If comment`dataType: 'json',`, then see ["02.07.2013","01.07.2013"].

If instead of `echo json_encode($output_value);` use `echo $output_value;` then see long list of `ArrayArrayArrayArrayArray`.

If inside `foreach` use `var_dump($output_value);` then see like this

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(1) "6" } 
...............
array(2) { [0]=> string(10) "02.07.2013" [1]=> string(10) "01.07.2013" }
```

Seems `echo $output[$key][0]` inside foreach does what is necessary...

**Finally** made conclusion that must use such kind of code

```
foreach ($output[record_date] as $key => $output_value) {
echo $output_value. ' output value<br>';
echo $output[other_name_from_html_input][$key]. ' output date selector value<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) actually does what you need.

```
parse_str($_POST['Values'], $output);
foreach ($output as $key => $output_value) {
    echo json_encode($output_value);
}
```

Your problem was that you don't understand how foreach loop works. `$output_value` is already value of the array element for current iteration, so you don't need to use it with indexes. If you want to use indexes you should use them with the original array like this:

```
foreach ($output as $key => $output_value) {
    echo json_encode($output[$key]);
}
```

Read carefully: [**PHP: foreach**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

But there is something that confusing me. Why are you passing serialized form data as a single value, when you can pass it as post data itself? In this case you don't need to use `parse_str()` and your code goes this:

**JS:**

```
var values = $("form").serialize();
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
data: values,
dataType: 'json',
```

**PHP:**

```
foreach ($_POST as $value) {
    echo json_encode($value);
}
```

Comment: With Ajax I need also to pass `<td id` like this `data: { 'clickedId' : $(this).closest('td').attr('id'), 'Values' : values },`

Comment: With `foreach ($output as $i=>$output_value ) {
echo json_encode($output_value);
}` also get nothing.... And the same with `echo json_encode($output[$i]);` But `echo json_encode($output['record_date']);` outside foreach is working...

Comment: Copy and past my first code example. I just tested it and it worked for me. http://pastebin.com/UfPAc2ET If it did't work use `var_dump($output_value)` inside the foreach loop to see what's going wrong.

Comment: Not as expected. I experimented. In question after update wrote what have got... at the moment can not understand why code works in such a way